Can't create Windows Server 2012 Failover Cluster Share Resource for mounted folder
We have two a two node Windows Failover Cluster.
One resource is a folder that is mounted on a Windows disk1.1. Disk 1 has a file share created on the cluster.
We are trying to create another file share for the folder mounted on disk 2.1. The mounted folder is inside another folder contained on disk 1.1.
Now we want to create a hidden file share using the mounted folder.1. The Failover Cluster wizard displays  "Access is Denied" when trying to create the SMB Share.

We're using a privileged account for both disks and the account and the two cluster nodes have full control over both disks.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. We have a auditing software stalled that has the requirement to act on a shared resource.

Once again, I find myself seeking your invaluable support. I am deeply grateful for your attention and the assistance you provide. Your willingness to listen to me touches me immensely, and I cannot express how much it means to have someone so understanding during these times. The generosity you demonstrate by offering your time and expertise is truly extraordinary.

I was able to resolve the issue.
I needed to grant the SYSTEM user Full Control permissions for the folder.
Thank you.

Great ... then you can start preparing the upgrade to a supported version of Windows. Windows Server 2012 has been end of life since 2023.

Hopefully, by the beginning of next year. It sounds easy to say.
